# New in Python. {using Spyder)

Tags: python

I am taking "DATA ANALYSIS AN INTERPRETATION. 
Never used Python.
I am trying to follow the lecture Video and getting this error. I have connected to the folder that has my CSV file.
Please help.

[image]

Comment: The error seems pretty clear to me. You're using as an argument for the `pandas.read_csv`  method a filename `2012_2016_PED.csv` that Python says is incorrect, because there is *no such file* to be found. Try putting the whole path to the file, e.g.: `'c:\\folders\\where\\file\\is\\2012_2016_PED.csv'`. Also, please specify the version of Python you're using (e.g., Python 3.6)

Comment: @flen, Why make the barrier to entry so high for a newbie?  The implicit question is "Why can't it find my file?".  We can help with that.  The version of python is, at least at this stage, irrelevant.  Let's make SO a friendlier place, eh?

Comment: @Ian sorry for any malapropism, I didn't mean to be rude. I usually log in late at night, so I didn't mean to be dry, I was probably just tired and tried to be objective. If you check my comment, you can see I lay for the OP useful tips to learn more (instead of simply saying "do exactly this"). This was how I learned. Anyway, my apologies to Christine Wacta if I sounded rude

Comment: thank youFlen and Thank you Ian so much. this is very intimidating and I am really hoping to get it. I am using 3.6 . tks again. I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the python script is in the same folder/directory as your csv file. Otherwise, add the directory path before the filename such as

`data=pandas.read_csv("your_directory_path/filename.csv")`

Comment: Great.Thank you so much.

Comment: @ChristineWacta If this person answered your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: How do I do that? By clicking the check mark? Sorry.